# In Javascript / NodeJS return current date adjusting for timezone, then find UTC equivalent of user's time at 6am

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime

Sorry if the title is a little convoluted. I'm bashing my head against the floor with times in `NodeJS` / `Javascript`. I can get the current UTC time like this:

```
var currentTime = Date.now();
```

I can get the current time for a user who is, for example, in the `-3` timezone like this:

```
var offsetTime = Date.now() + (numTimeZone * 3600000);
```

But how do I get the local user time at, say, 6am, converted to UTC?

**Practical application**:

What I'm trying to do is create an auto-emailer which sends an email to a user at 6am in their local time. My server is in one timezone and they will be in another, so I'm trying to standardise it against UTC so every minute I can set my server to check the `currentUTC` time, then check what the user's 6am time is converted to UTC (`local6am`), and if the `currentUTC > local6am` then an email should be sent.

What's the best way to achieve this? Preferably without using a library if possible.

Comment: Try **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)** this will help you.

Comment: @bios I've seen several mentions of `momentJS` in similar questions but from the docs I can't figure out how to achieve what I'm after with this library. If you can, post the solution as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

### Utc to Local

```
moment.utc('2014-02-19 05:24:32 AM').toDate();
```

### Local to utc

**Read [this documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).**

MomentJS is parsing the date as a locale date-time. If no hour is given, it is assuming midnight.

Then, you convert it to UTC, so it is shifted, according to your local time, forward or backwards. If your are in UTC+N, then you will get the previous date.

```
moment(new Date('02-19-2014')).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString()

moment(new Date('02-19-2014 12:00')).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString()
```

(or)

You can try this:

```
moment.utc('07-18-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY')

moment.utc('07-18-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You do not need to call `toString` explicitly.